# New Wolfram Warptangent 10.1 cold wallet transaction signing mechanism

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage, wolfram-warptangent

According to the Wolfram Warptangent, [Point Release 1 notes](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.10.1), Monero has `improved and fixed the cold wallet transaction signing mechanism`

What improvements were made? What are the new cold wallet functionalities that did not exist prior this point release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It introduced most of the commands mentioned [in this guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2916/57):

- import & export outputs
- import & export key images
- offline transaction generation
- pushing transactions generated offline to the network

Some bugs were observed during testing, which were fixed prior to the point release. Also, I'm not sure it was even possible to perform cold spending prior to this release (maybe via RPC, but definetely not with commands available in the old release)