# Unable to import outputs

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage

I'm following the instructions on here https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2916 to set up a cold and hot wallet. In the hot wallet I ran `export_outputs outs` which successfully generated the with the outputs. After moving the file `outs` to my cold device I ran `import_outputs outs` in the cold wallet. I get the error message `Error: Bad output export file magic in outs`.

Am I doing something terribly wrong or is there a bug?

EDIT:
On the hot wallet I was using a dynamically linked executable I built from the source on github but on the cold wallet I was using the officially built statically linked executable. When I switched to the official build on the hot wallet as well it worked! Is this behavior intended?

Comment: Try with full path, for example `import_outputs "~/fullpath/to/thefile/outs"`. There was a video guide based on that guide, which said you must specify the full path or it doesn't work. Let me know if it solved the problem and I'll update my guide as well.

Comment: @JollyMort I get the same error even when using the full path. The wallet definitely finds file. When I give a filename that doesn't exist there's a different error message.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. I don't think it's intended, the files are meant to be portable - but if you build from master it should not be considered stable and problems are to be expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a portability issue with the wallet (i.e., the wallet cache file, exported outputs, unsigned/singed transfers) which was fixed only after the release of the 0.10.1 binary, see pull requests [#1462](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1462) and [#1515](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1515).

What happened in your scenario is that the outputs exported from the recent master build are in the new portable file format and thus cannot be read by the release 10.1 binary which uses the old unportable file format. Output files exported using the 10.1 binary can be read from your cold wallet that uses the same 10.1 binary.