# Error using "import_outputs": failed to authenticate ciphertext

Tags: cold-storage

I'm trying to set up offline signing using CLI. My setup is as follows: I have a fully synced (via remote node) view only wallet on Mac OS X and I have a cold wallet set up on Raspberry Pi (OS: Ubuntu Mate).  Following [this guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/is-there-any-way-to-construct-a-transaction-manually/2916) I exported the outputs from the hot wallet.

When trying to import the file to the cold wallet, it tells me "Error: failed to decrypt outputs: Failed to authenticate criphertext".

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This means that the exported outputs couldn't be properly decrypted on the importing side, which can only happen when the wallets on the two sides have different addresses. Are you sure you imported the outputs to the correct wallet file?

Comment: This is exactly what went wrong - apologies. Pretty dumb mistake.

Comment: stoffu, please feel free to add this as an answer.