# wallet cli v0.12 : " Error : Failed to import Key images"

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, key-image

I've already created some view only wallet using --generate-from-view-key and importing key images, but today i've an issue doing this last step with Wallet cli v0.12.

I've the following message when i try to import key images in my view only wallet :

```
Error : Failed to import Key images
```

Can someone please help me?

thank you Regards,

Comment: The log file might have more information.

Comment: Ok, finally i've got it, I did not remember to export output first from my cold wallet (synchronized with the network)

For those who want to create a watch-only wallet, you can find the good tutorial here ==>

https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2916

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i've got it, I did not remember to export output first from my cold wallet (synchronized with the network)

For those who want to create a watch-only wallet, you can find the good tutorial here ==>

https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2916