# How to check balance of Cold Storage Monero Wallet, easily, when privacy of balance is not an issue?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, cold-storage, viewkey

I am aware similar questions have been asked - but I could not find the exact answer I seek.

In the situation of:

1. The user has a cold storage wallet, made on an airgapped computer,
   and has written down both the mnemonic seed / public key / view key.
2. The user has received multiple deposits to this wallet, with has no record of the transactions ID's and/or some transfers sent with
   no transaction ID.
3. The user does not care if the world can see their balance - but funds must be safe.
4. Seeking a solution using either a website, or Monero Gui Wallet. (no cli)

How can the user simply check the balance of their cold store wallet under these conditions?  Are there any security issues with the above conditions?

--

It seems like it should be as simple as just entering one's view key into a website and/or Monero Gui Client.  Is it actually that simple? How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view key detects incoming funds, and that is not enough to determine balance.

There is an easy way to do so, however: import your account on mymonero.com. There is a (currently) 1 monero fee for the blockchain scanning, but this will end up showing you your final balance. Of course, your wallet isn't cold anymore by that time.

A less easy solution, which keeps your wallet cold, is to export key images from your cold wallet, so the matching hot wallet can compute the final balance. See [Can the import\export key images command can be used to check the balance of a paperwallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1698/can-the-import-export-key-images-command-can-be-used-to-check-the-balance-of-a-p) for the details.