# What's a quick way to view my Monero Balance without downloading the blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

My transaction has been successful, but I'm sitting here waiting for the monero gui wallet to download the blockchain. It's showing my balance as 0 which seems to be a common issue.

Answer (score 1):

This [similar question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain) explains how you can connect your GUI to a remote node to verify your balance. For a more technical, but more secure method read about how to use [view keys and key images](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5788/how-to-check-balance-of-cold-storage-monero-wallet-easily-when-privacy-of-bala) to verify a balance without exposing your private keys to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

[MyMonero](https://mymonero.com/) would probably be the easiest method. Keep in mind that even though MyMonero is considered trustworthy, sending your private anywhere is a security concern.